# AC Clutch Not Engaging After Timing Belt Replacement

Tags: ac, chrysler, pt-cruiser

**Vehicle:** 2007 Chrysler PT Cruiser

Had my timing belt replaced saturday (Yesterday) as maintenance for the car; everything seemed perfect when I drove it afterwards but the temps outside were chilly enough that I didn't try out the AC.

Today it got pretty warm, and I tried turning on the AC and was dismayed to find that *nothing happened*, didn't hear/feel the compressor kick on, the air coming from the fans didn't get any cooler....

Normally my air conditioning in this car is ice cold, and was working perfectly the last time I tried using it about a week ago.

Part of the work that was done with the timing belt was to 'check the drive belts', so my first instinct was "Oh, perhaps he replaced the serpentine belt and didn't use the one that hooks up the A/C" ; I went and looked and it appears that the belt is connected to the air compressor.

I turned on the car and checked, and the clutch never appears to engage - the clutch itself is never spinning, even though the pulley on the air compressor is spinning as the belt moves.

The clutch doesn't try engaging and then stop - it never appears to engage at all.

Is there an obvious cause of this type of issue as a result of a timing belt replacement?

Please let me know if there are troubleshooting steps I need to take on my own / would be better for me to take on my own before bringing it into a shop.

**Update:** After being asked whether the 'energizer wire' was hooked up, I went back and opened up the hood, and from the limited view from the top I was eventually able to spot the following (see image), what appears to be a disconnected cable at the very back of the air compressor, which I wasn't able to see earlier when I was looking at the compressor head on from the side panel of my car (On this vehicle the air compressor is located behind the passenger side tire near the ground, behind the firewall)

I can't see this connector clearly enough to see what that inside bit of that white connector is, but it does look as if that's supposed to be sitting on that round orange bit next to it (apologies if that's not orange I'm color deficient)

[image]

Comment: Have you checked to ensure the energizer wire is hooked up to the clutch?

Comment: While I was looking at it there was a plug that was plugged in, had two wires on it, I pushed on it to make sure it was in all the way.... I'll dig into it tomorrow to check in more detail and also to get a voltage from that cable as well to see if it's putting out anything when the AC should be on

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Added an image here with what I found, could that be the energizer wire? This was located behind the air compressor

Comment: That looks exactly like what I was talking about. The grey connector behind the green socket. Looks like a match made in A/C heaven :o)

Comment: "could that be the energizer wire? This was located behind the air compressor " No, but it can keep the compressor from engaging if it is a low pressure switch.